Managing of consumers in Redis Streams
I will autoscale consumers using k8s KEDA based on new items in Redis Streams.
I wonder how to manage consumers in Redis. Is there a way to delete them automatically if no items are pending, or do I need to remove consumers manually (e.g. after processing finishes)?

I've ended up reusing predefined names and keeping them in Redis keys.
